# Setting up foreign key constraint in MySQL for use with Yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, constraints

So -- I have two tables that I'm trying to relate: tournament and match. They can be outlined as followed:

```
tournament   
    -id (int)   
    -league (varchar)   
    -status (varchar)  
    -create_time (datetime)   
    -update_time (datetime)

match   
    -id (int)   
    -tournament_id (int)   
    -status (varchar)  
    -create_time (datetime)   
    -update_time (datetime)
```

I'm attempting to add a foreign key constraint on the match table with the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE 'match' ADD CONSTRAINT
('FK_match_tournament') FOREIGN KEY
('tournament_id') REFERENCES
'tournament' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

however, I am getting the following error message from MySQL:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
''match' ADD CONSTRAINT ('FK_match_tournament') FOREIGN KEY ('tournament_id') REF'
at line 1
```

I looked at the syntax for adding FK constraints on the MySQL website, and everything looks right to me.  Any ideas?

First Suggestion (manuelpedrera):

```
ALTER TABLE `match` ADD CONSTRAINT ('FK_match_tournament') FOREIGN KEY ('tournament_id') REFERENCES `tournament` ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Results:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('FK_match_tournament') FOREIGN KEY ('tournament_id') REFERENCES `tournament` ('' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out 'match' is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use regular quotes when referring to a table.

Instead of `ALTER TABLE 'match'`

use

```
ALTER TABLE match
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `match`
```

**Edit 1:**

Try with this

```
ALTER TABLE `match` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`tournament_id`) REFERENCES  `tournament`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: Can you post the full SQL query that you are using after changes?

Comment: Tried your edit: #1005 - Can't create table 'sarena.#sql-1618_1b1' (errno: 150) (<a href="server_engines.php?engine=InnoDB&amp;page=Status&amp;token=a6086a0a38a9c2fbe4646457c7968c56">Details...</a>)

Comment: That's weird, I've tried myself with my own phpMyAdmin and it worked. Make sure that your tables are set to **InnoDB** instead of **MyISAM** and try again!

Comment: Well, I don't know what's the problem then. I would check that table and field names are all ok. If you are using phpMyAdmin, you could also stablish the relationship manually by clicking on a table and then in the **Relationships view** link at the bottom...

Comment: Relationships view is disabled in my PhpMyadmin, but the table and column names are right on the money.